# Convert MPadded MathML tag to LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, mathml

I try to convert a MathML document to a LaTeX. MathML have a mpadded tag that modify an inside box. They have following attributes:

- depth (sets or increments the depth);
- height (sets or increments the height);
- width (sets or increments the width);
- lspace (sets or increments the horizontal position);
- voffset (sets or increments the vertical position).

I try to use `\moveleft` command for shift box, but have an error (you can't use `\moveleft' in math mode). Can LaTeX change box size in math mode? If so how can i achieve a mpadded functionality.

[image: lspace and voffset] [image: width, height and depth]